# Doubt about the norm of the gradient vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is it possible to say that the gradient vector norm at a point $ (x, y, z) $ is the smallest rate of change? Considering a function $ f (x, y, z) $

Comment: What do you mean by "rate of change" and by "smallest" ?
The norm of the gradient vector can indicate how much the function will increase/decrease when locally moving around the point (x,y,z). 
If you choose a direction vector $c$, then $\nabla f\cdot c$ will give how much the value of the function will change when going in the direction $c$.

Answer (score 0):

At a point $p = (x,y,z)$, look at all the unit vectors $u$ with their tails at $p$. We can compute the instantaneous rate of change of $f$ in the direction $u$ by taking the following derivative:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}f(p + tu) = \nabla f(p) \cdot u.
$$
The equality is an exercise in the chain rule. But using this formula, we can see that the rate of change is a scalar, as expected, and it is largest (that is, most positive), when the vectors $\nabla f(p)$ and $u$ point in the same direction. That tells us that the direction of the gradient vector $\nabla f(p)$ would be the direction of **most positive** change, and the direction of $-\nabla f(p)$ would be the direction of **most negative** change.

If we pick a direction $u$ perpendicular to $\nabla f$, then the instantaneous rate of change of $f$ would be $0$ in the direction of $u$ (another consequence of the formula above, and the geometric interpretation of the dot product). Depending on how you use the language, a direction perpendicular to the gradient could fairly be said to be a direction of "smallest change" as you said in your post, because this is a direction where the change is smallest **in magnitude.**

The ambiguity in the way we use the words *greatest* and *smallest* makes us be more precise in order to clarify the picture we have in mind, or the idea we want to convey.